# How to change the values of a column based on two conditions in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset where I have the time in a game and the time of an event.

```
  EVENT     GAME
  0:34      0:43
  NaN       0:23
  2:34      3:43
  NaN       4:50
```

I want to replace the NaN in the EVENT column where GAME < 0.24 by the value in the GAME column.

```
 df['EVENT'][(df['GAME'] < '0:24') & (df['EVENT'] == 'NaN')] = df['GAME']
```

I have tried this but it dosen't work. Sorry if it is obvious. I am new to Python.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) for check `NaN`:

```
df.loc[(df['GAME'] < '0:24') & (df['EVENT'].isnull()), 'EVENT'] = df['GAME']
print (df)

  EVENT  GAME
0  0:34  0:43
1  0:23  0:23
2  2:34  3:43
3   NaN  4:50
```

Another solution with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
mask = (df['GAME'] < '0:24') & (df['EVENT'].isnull())
df['EVENT'] = df['EVENT'].mask(mask, df['GAME'])
print (df)
  EVENT  GAME
0  0:34  0:43
1  0:23  0:23
2  2:34  3:43
3   NaN  4:50
```

Or [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['EVENT'] = np.where(mask, df['GAME'], df['EVENT'])
print (df)
  EVENT  GAME
0  0:34  0:43
1  0:23  0:23
2  2:34  3:43
3   NaN  4:50
```